# Can I programmatically change the class bound to a User Control XAML

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In this User Control XAML if I have initially

```
<UserControl x:Class="someclass"
```

Can I Can I programmatically change the class ? Where and How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the class type when instantiated but you can instantiate a new object.

**Alternative 1:**

[This is not something I have tried myself, but I think you should be able to pull it off if you give the control a name. Then programatically you could do this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="someclass" x:Name="myControl" ...
```

In code do:

```
this.myControl = new SomeOtherUserControl();
```

**Alternative 2:**

Create an interface that provides the behaviour you wish to change at runtime in your control.
And have your User Control contain an instance that implements this behaviour. You can then change the instance at runtime.

Something like:

```
interface ISpecialControlBehaviour
{
...
}

class DefaultBehaviour: ISpecialControlBehaviour
{
}

class Behaviour2 : ISpecialControlBehaviour
{
}
```

Your user control:

```
class MyUserControl
{
   // use this property to change behaviour at runtime.
   ISpecialControlBehaviour Behaviour {get;set;}
   MyUserControl()
   {
      Behaviour  = DefaultBehaviour();
   }
}
```

If not clear let me know and I will extend the code sample ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much, will re-read multiple times to understand before trying :)

Answer (score 2):

No, as this is a compile time directive. [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752309.aspx)

You should use a backing class that you can exchange by any mean, and either use properties or an [ObjectDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to access bound methods.

Answer (score 2):

I may be off in my answer, but another option to switch Controls is to to put them inside a Content Control.
and than in the code you can say:

```
ContentControl.Content = new MyUserControl();
```

Comment: Very interesting idea I'll try thanks (if it works you'll get the right answer :))

Comment: It should work, and it's simple.
just give the ContentControl a name, and in code change the content.
let me know if there are problems

Comment: It works for some UserControl and not for some, maybe it's due to some codebehind I put will have to investigate further tomorrow. Hope I can make it work all the time that would be the best solution :)